# Google Map Api - How to know if a coordinates is accessible by pedestrian

Tags: dictionary, coordinates

I'm trying to figure if there is a way to ask the Google Map Api to know if a random gps coordinates like :
48,277373 
2,4883883
Is accessible by pedestrian ?
It should be possible because if I ask Google Map to lead me in the middle of a river, it will lead me just on the nearest point before the water.
But I'm not sure how about I can get this information by providing the coordinates.
Thanks for your help :-)